# how to put the whole program in a infinite loop controlled by command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

Programming Language : C

I'd like to put my program controlled by command line arguments..

I mean, unless I enter "quit" it should keep on executing based upon the arguments I enter to do..

Comment: if it's 'executing' in an infinite loop, it won't even be able to take your input through command prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean in that way..

Comment: let me put this way, I need to execute the program based upon given arguments and should only terminate if I enter "quit"

Comment: Why don't you use signals? Then you could stop your execution by hitting Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and comment right, you want to check for input inside a loop, and if it's "quit" you should exit the program (not the loop)?

The functions you need to look up are `scanf` and `strcmp`:

```
while (1)
{
    char input[256];

    /* Do some things here... */

    scanf("%s", input);
    if (strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
        break;  /* exit loop */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question literally gives me this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[i], "quit") == 0)
            break;
        doSomething(argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Not really an infinite loop, but if you're really going after command line arguments, an infinite loop is probably not reasonable. But I'm 99% certain you're really looking for Joachim Pileberg's answer (i.e. not using command line arguments, but getting input from the standard input stream).