# how to put the whole program in a infinite loop controlled by command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line

Programming Language : C

I'd like to put my program in a infinite loop controlled by command line arguments..

I mean, unless I enter "quit" it should keep on executing based upon the arguments I enter to do..

Comment: Basically you read from comand line, parse the commands so you can filter command and arguments, invoke the command, read from the line again, put that in a infinite loop. 
Command design pattern would be helpful. 
http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx

Comment: Exact duplicate of the (closed!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010514/how-to-put-the-whole-program-in-a-infinite-loop-controlled-by-command-line-argum

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything about your target platform, it is hard to make specific recommendations. But *one* way you can do it is with a "state machine." [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design) is a rather nice stackoverflow question that can give you some ideas. In particular look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/1648098#1648098) answer.

Comment: Actually, its a kind of game. where the program open a square grid and I have to give commands to the grid so as to put a cross mark in a specific square. after every command I give to it, it should execute it and ask me for another.. unless I give "quit" command to it.. the program shouldn't terminate.  

actually, I couldn't able to understand what's there is the link.

Comment: The words "here" and "this" in my answer are hyperlinks to another stackoverflow question.

Comment: yeah! I was referring them,.. I couldn't understand.

Comment: FWIW, *every useful program* is a state machine.  ("Hello world" might or might not qualify, but i'm not getting into that argument.)  If there's looping or recursion, or if you otherwise ever act based on the values of variables, you have a state machine.

Comment: @cHao, I agree that at a fundamental level every useful program is a "state machine." In this context, however, "state machine" refers to a particular high-level construct (as described in the other stackoverflow question). When a C-programmer talks about implementing a state machine, they're usually not referring strictly to the abstract notion of state machines as described in computability theory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]);
{
        char cmd = '\0';
        char quit = 0;

        while(quit==0) {
                cmd = fgetc(stdin);  

                switch(cmd) {
                        case 'q':
                        {
                          quit =1;
                          break;
                        }
                        // process other cases.
                }
        }
        fprintf(stdout,"Quiting\n");
}
```

Comment: where does q come from in case q: ?

Comment: it was a typing mistake. it is 'q'. Edit has fixed it.

Comment: q is just 1 char, use string compare to check if "quit" has been typed.

Comment: @user1027046 then you'll have to elaborate on what you want it to do.

Comment: I thought it would be a very simpler principle to extend. Anyway, you can do fgets to acquire complete string first and do string compare. Is there really a tricky situation more than we are discussing here?

Comment: Actually, its a kind of game. where the program open a square grid and I have to give commands to the grid so as to put a cross mark in a specific square. after every command I give to it, it should execute it and ask me for another.. unless I give "quit" command to it.. the program shouldn't terminate

Comment: The above example will do exactly what you want. Just implement the commands other than "q".

Comment: @user1027046 Ok. So i guess i answered that question here. Since you are putting this up as a whole game one wouldn't really want to put the entire game inside the switch case so may be i will be able to run the polling loop in separate thread; but all this is really easy to extend. So I am not quite getting exactly what help you need it with?

Comment: @user1027046 so instead of using the switch, use `strcmp`... `while(!quit) { nextCmd = readCmd(); if(strcmp(nextCmd, "quit") == 0) quit = 1; else handleCmd(nextCmd); }`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you can use the following function : system() in stdlib.h
where the syntax is as follows:

                 int system(const char *command);
here you can pass any shell command as a string argument